# Send emails from static website hosted on google storage (using google services)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-workspace

I just created a static website that is hosted on google storage. My domain is also registered with google domains and I have a business G suite account.

My static website has a 'contact us' form and I wonder if it is possible to use gmail or gsuite (or any gcp services) to send the content of the form as an email to my gmail address.

I know there's services like mailgun, etc. But I'd rather do it using tools from google if possible.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good option that you can use, within the range of Google products, to achieve the goal of sending emails via Contact Form, with your static website.

This option is actually easy and very simple to configure, I would say, which it's to use the serveless product Cloud Functions. To provide some context on it, you can make the functions trigger via HTTPS request, so it works with your site and you will be able to use it for free, for up to 625 thousands forms submissions per month. I would recommend you to give a look at it, in this complete tutorial [here](https://medium.com/the-level-up/serverless-contact-form-handling-for-static-websites-8e075ec2efd8), where you can find the steps.

In addition to this option, you can use Mailgun as you mentioned, but in association with GCP products, to give you this service. You can use Mailgun to send the emails, Cloud Datastore to keep records of it and Cloud Functions to work with these two services. More information can be found in this similar case [here](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2018/07/gcp-contact-form/).

To summarize, as you would prefer to use tools from Google, to follow the first tutorial, where you will be using Cloud Functions only, to configure your service.